# Multiple Variables in PHP URL with HTTP Referrer

Tags: php, mysql, http, url

I'm trying to create a custom URL with HTTP_Referrer (where they came from), the date, and an incrementing traffic URL

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

mysql_select_db('database');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (TrafficID, ClickURL, CreateDate) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['TrafficID'])."',  '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ClickURL'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['CreateDate'])."')");
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET out = out + 1 WHERE ID = $TrafficID")or     die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID = $TrafficID") or     die(mysql_error()); 
$info = mysql_fetch_array($data); 
$variable['TrafficID'] = "id"; 
$variable['ClickURL'] = "url";
$variable['CreateDate'] = "date"; 
$value['TrafficID'] = "mysql_fetch_array($data);"; 
$value['ClickURL'] = "$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']";
$variable['CreateDate'] = "$today"; 
$link = "http://www.example.com/page.php";
$link .= "?";
$link .= $variable['TrafficID'] . "=" . $value['TrafficID'];
$link .= "&";
$link .= $variable['ClickURL'] . "=" . $value['ClickURL'];
$link .= "@";
$link .= $variable['CreateDate'] . "=" . $value['CreateDate'];
echo "<a href='" . $link . "'>Click here!</a>";`
```

Ideally the URL would look like http://www.example.com/page.php?TrafficID&ClickURL@date and this would all be stored in the database, however I can't seem to get it to work, can anyone point where I made a mistake?

**UPDATE**

```
$value['ClickURL'] = "$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']";
$today = date("Ymd");  
$variable['CreateDate'] = "$today"; 
$link = "http://www.example.com/page.php";
$link .= "?";
$link .= $variable['TrafficID'] . "=" . $value['TrafficID'];
$link .= "&";
$link .= $variable['ClickURL'] . "=" . $value['ClickURL'];
$link .= "&";
$link .= $variable['CreateDate'] . "=" . $value['CreateDate'];
echo "<a href='" . $link . "'>Click here!</a>";`
```

Changed @ to & and reformatted my date value

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want to achieve?

Comment: You don't assign a value to your GET values (page.php?TrafficID=123&ClickURL=some_url&CreateDate=20130218). You also don't do any validations of the data that is given through the GET. Also in these kind of situations it's wise to use Database Rollbacks, in case some of the queries fail.

Comment: Lobo, I'm trying to track clickthroughs on ads through the URLs when they come to the site, so I can track every click (not my idea, my clients), so no two urls will be duplicate 
so example.com/id=1&url=google.com@2012-02-18

Also Allendar, can you explain a little more?

Comment: That @ sign doesn't work well for URL usage. It's better to just make it another GET value, like you actually already did in your first mysql_query() :). Did you also test the blocks individually? Writing these kind of code it's best to do it step-by-step and also add if-else checks to see if you actually get the $_GET data you want. Your problem now is the wrong implementation of the URL-format. Use CreateDate=2012-02-18 instead. Also, try formatting the data like this "2012_02_18" OR "20120218"

Comment: Made some of the changes you suggested, can you give me an example of an if else statement that would work well with this?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? insert a new record and then using that records values to create an url? or do you just want to create a new url with the http_refer and the date (incrementing the traffic id can be done by mysql)?